# AWS Glue: using ResolveChoice to project to timestamp drops field when converting to parquet

Tags: apache-spark, parquet, aws-glue

Trying to convert a series of compressed gz to parquet format.

In the processes trying to do some transformations. (reduce number of fields, cast etc) After doing some debugging it seems when I try to project a field to timestamp the resulting parquet file is missing the field.

relevant python snippet:

```
import sys
from awsglue.transforms import *
from awsglue.utils import getResolvedOptions
from pyspark.context import SparkContext
from awsglue.context import GlueContext
from awsglue.job import Job

args = getResolvedOptions(sys.argv, ['JOB_NAME'])

sc = SparkContext()
glueContext = GlueContext(sc)
spark = glueContext.spark_session
job = Job(glueContext)
job.init(args['JOB_NAME'], args)

datasource0 = glueContext.create_dynamic_frame.from_options(connection_type = "s3", connection_options = {"paths": ["<s3 path>"]}, format = "json", transformation_ctx = "read")

datasource0 = ApplyMapping.apply(frame = datasource0, mappings = [("timestamp", "string", "timestamp", "long"), ("name", "string", "name", "string"), ("value", "string", "value", "string"), ("type", "string", "type", "string")])
datasource0 = SelectFields.apply(frame = datasource0, paths = ["timestamp", "name", "value", "type"])

# here is where the parquet schema changes 
# the timestamp column is no longer there in parquet tools

datasource0 = ResolveChoice.apply(frame = datasource0, specs = [('timestamp','project:timestamp'), ('name','cast:string'), ('type','cast:string'), ('value','cast:string')])


glueContext.write_dynamic_frame.from_options(datasource0, connection_type = "s3", connection_options = {"path": "<another s3 path>"}, format = "parquet", format_options = {'compression': 'gzip'}, transformation_ctx = "write")

job.commit()
```

Up until the ResolveChoice choice if I do parquet-tools on the resulting parquet file i would see four fields.

However after using that line I get this:

```
message spark_schema {
  optional binary name (UTF8);
  optional binary value (UTF8);
  optional binary type (UTF8);
}
```

the timestamp field missing.

project:  Resolves a potential ambiguity by projecting all the data to one of the possible data types. For example, if data in a column could be an int or a string, using a project:string action produces a column in the resulting DynamicFrame where all the int values are converted to strings.

so I was wondering is there no way to project to a timestamp type?